# What is the type of the value 1.0e+1

Tags: c, floating-point

Does `1.0e+1` return a `float` value or `int` value?

When I print `1.0e+1` it gives `10` but when I do `sizeof(1.0e+1)` it gives me `8`.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ if you want to know about C?

Comment: If you use `printf` with `%s` (or some other nonsense format specifier), *warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type '<actual type you wanted to know>'*

Comment: All floating point values are by default `double` unless suffixed by e.g. `f`.

Comment: @NathanOliver this applies to both languages, this is one case where it's actually ok to have both tags I think.

Comment: Because printing `1.0e+1` and `sizeof(1.0e+1)` is not the same. Simply because `1.0e+1` is **not** `sizeof(1.0e+1)`.

Answer (score 7):

> *Does `1.0e+1` return a `float` value or `int` value?*

Ans: None. As is it written, it *represents* a `double`.

<sub>*Nitpick: Let's use the term **represent** instead of **return***</sub>

I think you're confused. IHMO, you need to know about the proper usage of the conversion specifiers.

1. to print a float, you need to use `%f`
2. to print a `sizeof` output, you need to use `%zu`

That said, *printing* `1.0e+1` means printing the *value* whereas, `sizeof(1.0e+1)` is essentially `sizeof(double)`, because, *floating point literal* is by default a `double`.

Related, from `C11` standard, chapter §6.4.4.2

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has type `float`. If suffixed by the letter ``l or `L`, it has type `long double`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a `double`, in your platform and compiler, `sizeof(double) == 8`, while `sizeof(float) == 4`, if you want it to be float `1.0E1f` would do it, and integer wouldn't have the decimal separator, but still `sizeof(1E1) == 8` i.e. it will also generate a `double`.

In other words, when you use exponent notation, it will always be a `double` unless you suffix the value with a `f`, which would generate a `float`, integers are not possible with this notation, but of course

```
int x = 1E1;
```

would make `x = 10;` and it would be an integer, because the `1E1` will be converted to `int`.

Comment: `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(float)` are implementation defined values.  Common implementation choices are `8` and `4`, but there are real compilers that have different sizes.    What is true is that `sizeof(1E1) == sizeof(double)`.

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you have an `e` suffix it becomes a [floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).

> A floating-point literals have two syntaxes. The first one consists of the following parts:
>   - nonempty sequence of decimal digits containing a decimal point character (defines significand)
>   - (optional) **e or E** followed with optional minus or plus sign and nonempty sequence of decimal digits (defines exponent)
>   - (optional) a suffix type specifier as a l, f, L or F

Also

> The suffix type specifier defines the actual type of the floating-point literal:
>   - **(no suffix) defines double**
>   - **f F defines float**
>   - l L defines long double

In this case, both of your examples are of type `double`. You would need a `f` suffix to declare `float` literals.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler sees the 1.0, it automatically becomes one of the floating point types.  So 1.0e1 is 10 which is the same as 10.0.  But sizeof returns the size of the datatype that is storing the value.  Since it returns 8, then it's a double.  The standard [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) defines the following types:

- float: 32-bits or 4 bytes
- double: 64-bits or 8 bytes
- long double: 80-bits or 10 bytes

It is generally bad coding practice to let the compiler set the data type.  So you will want to declare a variable and set it equal to the value.  However, I can only assume as to what you are doing because you didn't post any code.